# Sliding doors button with CSS 3 transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to do something simple with CSS 3 transitions but struggling with it. I have an image button with 2 states in it and when you hover over it i want the image to change to the `on` state.

So far so bog standard - this sliding doors technique has been around for donkeys years. The twist is I need it to fade nicely from one state to another i.e. you mouse over the button it fades out smoothly shifts itself up by 50% while opacity is set to 0 then fades back in again - and vice versa when you mouse out. Oh yeah, and it has to be done with an inline image not a background image as this is what the CMS I'm working with spits out.

I have achieved this using jQuery/CSS transitions to create a 'ghost' element behind the image that fades in when the image fades out. I am not happy with this and feel that there must be a better way to achieve it using just CSS transitions or at least keyframe animation. Any ideas?

Here is an example of the HTML button code that I have to work with:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="01_double.jpg" alt="The Stylist" height="198" width="396">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where is the css that you are trying? btw lol username ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be your CSS for webkit

```
a {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0%;
    position: relative;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-animation: ani 1s;
    left: -50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ani {
     0% {opacity: 1; left: 0%;}
    50% {opacity: 0; left: 0%;}
    51% {opacity: 0; left: -50%;}
   100% {opacity: 1; left: -50%;}
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsRL5/)

you can set the reverse animation in the mouseout settting it in reverse in the base state.

```
img {
   opacity: 1;
   left: 0%;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-animation: ani 1s reverse;
}
```

### [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/KsRL5/1/)

This has the problem that it animates also on page load.
If you want to avoid that, set this animation in a class and set the class to the element on page load.

Comment: Hi vals, thanks for this - this is basically as far as i had got, but i need the effect to reverse as well when you mouseout.

Comment: Added fiddle. (and comment)